# What is the purpose of additionalLocalClaims in Identity Server 4 SignInAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, claims

In Identity Server 4, Quick Start, `ExternalController.cs` - `CallBack` method, I found the following:

```
// this allows us to collect any additonal claims or properties
// for the specific prtotocols used and store them in the local auth cookie.
// this is typically used to store data needed for signout from those protocols.
var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
ProcessLoginCallbackForOidc(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

// issue authentication cookie for user
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, provider, localSignInProps, additionalLocalClaims.ToArray());
```

You can see the complete set of code at this link - [IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/ff2834873654aaec8b5ecc5fd49beb4dab1d7f89/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs)

I tried to add some claims to that `additionalLocalClaims` list by doing the following:

```
additionalLocalClaims.Add(new Claim("TestName", "TestValue"));
```

But it never appears in the UserClaims or AccessToken even though ClaimType "TestName" is included in ApiResource.

I would like to add some custom claims/values in AccessToken for Google Authentication and I thought additionalLocalClaims is the right one to append additional claims.

P.S.  I finally implemented `IProfileService` and could return the additional claims.  But I still want to know what's the use case of that `additionalLocalClaims` in `HttpContext.SignInAsync` extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are authentication-related extension methods on the HttpContext from ASP.NET Core to issue the authentication cookie and sign a user in , and you can add custom cliams to cookie for authentication session of Identity Server 4 .For example , you can add claims  which  needed for signout , some external idenity provider may issue a session id claim , you can involve it in local auth cookie via `additionalLocalClaims` , which could be used to perform single sign-out from external identity provider if user logout in your identity server . But the claims are kept in local auth cookie of IDS4 , they are not in ID token ,access token  and userinfo endpoint . You can implement `IProfileService` as you said to involve custom claims in tokens or userinfo endpoint .